# Animation in javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm trying to create an animation in javascript.

I created a canvas

```
<canvas id = "animation" width="1130" height="222"></canvas>
```

and what I want to do, is to add 3 images (+1 more which is the background),  and during each second I want to have 1 image shown and the other 2 hidden. 
What I have now is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('animation');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

background = new Image();
background.src = 'images/background.png';
background.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
}

var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = 'images/image1.png';
image1.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image1, 895, 61);
}

var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = 'images/image2.png';
image2.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image2, 895, 61);
}
var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = 'images/image3.png';
image3.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image3, 895, 61);
}

image1.style.visibility = "visible";
image2.style.visibility = "hidden";
image3.style.visibility = "hidden";

setTimeout(function(){
    image1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    image2.style.visibility = "visible";
    image3.style.visibility = "hidden";
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    image1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    image3.style.visibility = "visible";
    image2.style.visibility = "hidden";
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
    image3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    image1.style.visibility = "visible";
    image2.style.visibility = "hidden";
}, 3000);
```

however it does not work. All of them appear on the screen

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix two different things here: canvas and CSS.

The canvas works like (surprise!) a canvas: that means that once you draw something there it will stay there until you draw something else over it. Therefore, changing the css of the images on memory will have no effect.

You have two alternatives: the DOM route, just insert the images in the DOM without the canvas and you will be able to change their style, or the Canvas route, calling to context.drawImage INSIDE various `setTimeout`, so you draw a new image each second.

Comment: I'll go with Canvas route.
Now I'm trying to call `drawImage` inside `setTimeout`. 
but how can I hide the image, when I draw another one? 
i.e. when I draw image2, I want to hide image1 etc.

Comment: You can use context.clearRect(x,y,w,h) to clear a portion of the canvas, but if the next image will cover the previous one (as your code suggests) it is not necessary.

Comment: The next image is not going to cover the previous one, because they are not of the same dimensions. `context.clearRect(x, y, w, h)` does not work as well. Previously created images, are still on canvas.

Comment: Moreover, `context.clearRect(x,y,w,h)` is not a good idea. As I said in my initial post, I have a background image, visible at all the time, so `clearRect` will create a "hole" in the background.

Comment: Then just redraw the background to "clear" the canvas, and then draw the second picture.